# ftrace problem Is there something I'm missing?

Tags: kernel

When I try to mount command, it has some problem.

```
mount -t tracefs nodev /sys/kernel/tracing
mount: 'nodev'->'/sys/kernel/tracing': Device or resource busy
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is tracing already mounted under debugfs ? check `mount | grep debugfs  and ls /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/`

If yes you need to unmount and mount again